# WAP a c program for Bubble sort

Tags: c

Write a C program to perform bubble sort on an array of n elements.
I write the following code but the condition is that **stop the process if we find that the list is sorted in any intermediate point**

pls tell how i solve this??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void bubble_sort(int[], int);

void main() {
   int arr[30], num, i;

   printf("\nEnter no of elements :");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   printf("\nEnter array elements :");
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
      scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

   bubble_sort(arr, num);
   getch();
}

void bubble_sort(int iarr[], int num) {
   int i, j, k, temp;

   printf("\nUnsorted Data:");
   for (k = 0; k < num; k++) {
      printf("%5d", iarr[k]);
   }

   for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < num - 1; j++) {
         if (iarr[j] > iarr[j + 1]) {
            temp = iarr[j];
            iarr[j] = iarr[j + 1];
            iarr[j + 1] = temp;
         }
      }

      printf("\nAfter pass %d : ", i);
      for (k = 0; k < num; k++) {
         printf("%5d", iarr[k]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If at a certain iteration you notice that you did not need to do any swaps, what does it tell you about the list?

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to count or test if there was any swap when you iterate through the list elements in the inner loop, if there was no need to swap any element, that certainly means that the list is **sorted**.

Comment: I think this is the only way to answer to this question, anything else would be to solve the problem for the OP, which is not a good idea, since this requirement is most certainly a homework requirement.

Comment: The loops are also incorrect. Each iteration should *remove* the last-bubbled element from the sequence of comparators for all future iterations. There is no sense in traipsing through already-bubbled elements. Uptick btw.

Comment: @ysap inefficient. It will still work, but there is no need to continue into sorted data. In fact, the swap detection can be used dual-purpose to that end, noting the *last* element that was swapped-from, and not exceeding that element on the next pass.

Comment: @WhozCraig - yes... just wanted to emphasize that nuance.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the bubble sort is that on each iteration largest element in the list reaches at the end.
SO After first iteration largest element of the array reaches at the end. Similarly, at the second iteration second largest element in array reaches at the second last position and so on.

so you have to make some change in your j variable loop.
Make it like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < num - i; j++) {
         if (iarr[j] > iarr[j + 1]) {
            temp = iarr[j];
            iarr[j] = iarr[j + 1];
            iarr[j + 1] = temp;
         }
      }
```

By this J loop will iterate only to those elements which are not sorted.